# Recover remote DB after losing connection to a mapped network drive

Tags: sql-server

I have a remote DB on a local MS SQL Server. This DB is located on a network path by code a-la:

```sql
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'net use H: \\RemoteServerName\ShareName'
```

After the remote host was rebooted the local server would return

> The operating system returned the error 59(An unexpected network error occurred.) to SQL Server during a read at offset 0x00000000056000 in file ...

But the server still thinks that this BD is online!

The first attempt was to reset mapped drive:

```sql
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'net use * /delete /y'
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'net use H: \\RemoteServerName\ShareName'
```

It didn't help. Well, it restores the mapping, but not the DB connection.

Any attempt to `ALTER DATABASE`, `DBCC CHECKDB`, etc. was rejected with the same error.

So the only thing that helped was: restart SQL Server, map network drive, DBCC CHECKDB.

So the question is: is there a good way to recover a "visibly working" DB after network breakdown or remote host reboot? Using SSMS included.

There is a similar question with an answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/122660), but I'm not sure how to execute step 3 and if it is the only way to recover DB in this situation.

Comment: Don't host your database files on a network path; that is the real solution.

Comment: To add a actual solution to the problem. I would suggest you take the database offline, move the files to a local location, change the location of the files within SQL Server (using `ALTER DATABASE`) and then bring the database back online. Be prepared for data corruption though as the instance would not have "liked" having its connection cut to the files.

Comment: It's not really MINE, so I can't move it. There was/is not enough local disk space to store it, if I remember correctly.
I'll repeat: any attempt to ALTER DATABASE was rejected with the same error. Taking it offline is using ALTER statement. I can't detach it either.

Comment: *"It's not really MINE, so I can't move it."* That doesn't, if I am honest, make sense. If you are attaching it to *your* instance you are claiming ownership of said file. Like i said, the problem is you're using a file on a network share; don't. If you don't have the storage, either make some, install more storage, or use a different host for SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you for you kind advice. I'll take it heartily. I'm sure it will help. But it doesn't solve the given problem.

Comment: What about running SQL Server on the machine that hosts the file?